# catkin_make error melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this error after ran the `catkin_make` command line:

```
$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    /usr/bin/c++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:530: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I am using ubuntu 17.10 and installed  version: ros melodic. Could someone help me to fit it.

---

Edit: Here my setup output as suggested from you:

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/c++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 25 22:30 /usr/bin/c++ -> /etc/alternatives/c++
```

and:

```
$ echo $CXX
/usr/bin/g++
```

Currently, I try to reinstall and do the same thing and make it different error output, like:

```
catkin_make Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/user/catkin_ws/src
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/user/catkin_ws/devel
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/catkin_ws/install
-G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment   variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path   to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

Edit2:

I am currently using catkin to install and it cannot detect the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER. I tried to put all related files here for you to understanding my installation.

```
$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/user/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/user/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

This is CMakeError.log:
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory
```

This is the CMakeOutput.log:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/a1bcacec3398ff78b1d1a85b5f516cf4

and my CMakeList.txt

```
# toplevel CMakeLists.txt for a catkin workspace
# catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)

# search for catkin within the workspace
set(_cmd "catkin_find_pkg" "catkin" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_cmd}
  RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE _out
  ERROR_VARIABLE _err
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(NOT _res EQUAL 0 AND NOT _res EQUAL 2)
  # searching fot catkin resulted in an error
  string(REPLACE ";" " " _cmd_str "${_cmd}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (${_cmd_str}): ${_err}")
endif()

# include catkin from workspace or via find_package()
if(_res EQUAL 0)
  set(catkin_EXTRAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_out}/cmake")
  # include all.cmake without add_subdirectory to let it operate in same scope
  include(${catkin_EXTRAS_DIR}/all.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
  add_subdirectory("${_out}")

else()
  # use either CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH explicitly passed to CMake as a command line argument
  # or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from the environment
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    if(NOT "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" STREQUAL "")
      string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    endif()
  endif()

  # list of catkin workspaces
  set(catkin_search_path "")
  foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    if(EXISTS "${path}/.catkin")
      list(FIND catkin_search_path ${path} _index)
      if(_index EQUAL -1)
        list(APPEND catkin_search_path ${path})
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # search for catkin in all workspaces
  set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE TRUE)
  find_package(catkin QUIET
    NO_POLICY_SCOPE
    PATHS ${catkin_search_path}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
  unset(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE)

  if(NOT catkin_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was sourced before.")
  endif()
endif()

catkin_workspace()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294883/catkin_make-error-melodic/) by [dlrlr](https://answers.ros.org/users/35424/dlrlr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you actually have a C++ compiler installed?

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I would've assumed that would be installed automatically, but perhaps that is not true for your system.

Then `rm -rf /home/user/catkin_ws/{build,devel}` and try again.

---

Edit: and you can run `/usr/bin/c++`?

---

Edit2: your latest edit makes me wonder if you really do have a C++ compiler installed.

Please run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```

Then `rm -rf /home/user/catkin_ws/{build,devel}` and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dlrlr](https://answers.ros.org/users/35424/dlrlr/) on 2018-06-21**:
Yes, I already install C++ compiler, I actually checked. I tried your instructions but don't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-21**:
"don't work" is a bit vague. You cannot install the package, or even with that pkg it doesn't change the output of `catkin_make`?

Ignoring that: are you setting the `CXX` environment variable in your shell? What is the output of `ls -al /usr/bin/c++`? And of `echo $CXX`?

**Comment by [dlrlr](https://answers.ros.org/users/35424/dlrlr/) on 2018-06-25**:
Sorry to say, it didn't work

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
Then why did you mark the question as answered?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-26**:
I'm not sure what else to suggest. It seems there is a problem with CMake not being able to detect your C++ compiler.

Can you use CMake for C++ in a stand-alone project (ie: without ROS)?